# Best way to pass an optional parameter to a program

Tags: c++, parameters

In a couple of my programs, the program needs to know an IP address and a port to which it should connect or send data to.

The solution I have right is to ask for user input via the console - but this just doesn't look like a good solution to me for passing the parameters to the program in the long term. In a later stage of the project, these programs will probably run in a docker, which are managed by kubernetes. (I wasn't able to research about this yet, but it may make a solution better than another - yet my question is not only about that case).

Other informations which might be important: I am writing these programs in C++ and are quite new to software engineering and programming. I split up the code so that one class manages the functionality (e.g. sending data) and another manages getting user input, so I may write different versions with different parameter-passing solution if necessary. The "How to use" does not have to be self-explanatory, for each program there will be a readme explaining the "How to use".

There will probably always be a default version, which is used if no paramter is given (or default is explicitly choosed).

So my question: **What are good solutions (and their pro's and cons) for passing these parameters to a program?**

Things I thought of myself:

- Asking for user input in the console (doesn't look nice, is probably incompatible with docker)
- A file which contains this informations and from which the programs read
- Passing these informations as arguments to the main

Are there other solutions I didn't think of? What are usual ways to handle this? 
Any hint is usefull! Thank you!

Comment: https://12factor.net/config

Comment: see [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer: Use the main arguments (more preferably use `getopt` or some library to process them).

Longer answer:

You have multiple options here, one you did not mention was that you can use the environment variables. For the bigger projects, my order of loading the configuration is:

- sensible defaults (the most general)
- configuration files
- env variables
- main arguments (the most specific)

I don't think that it is good practice to load "parameters" from the stdin. I would use the stdin to load data, not the parameters.

Comment: What does "sensible default" mean in this contex? I would guess it means hard coded default option, but I'm really not sure...

Comment: Yes, you are right, they are hardcoded default options. Sensible in this context means that they make sense - more preferable if I use default values (I will not override them) the application will run somehow correctly.